# How to display the contents of the array, changing the structure id dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am trying to display the products in this array, however, I am not able to make it change the ids dynamically so that all products are displayed. So far I'm only able to display 1 product, because the id is fixed, as shown in the js below.

[image]

```js
//CAMISAS
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {

      j(document).on("click", "ul#menu li.nav-item#1", function() {
        j.getJSON('/api/V1/categories/1', function(data) {
          console.log(data.items);
          var myArray = data.items;
          //I tried to use For, but that way it only displays 1 product instead of all products in the array
          //for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {   

          var insertHtmlShirt = `<div class="card" id="${data.items[2].id}">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="${data.items[1].image}" alt=" "/>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${data.items[1].name}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">R$ ${data.items[1].price}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">COMPRAR</a>
            </div>
        </div>`;
          jQuery('div#Product').html(insertHtmlShirt);
          //}
        });
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-7">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="ItemProd" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 mobile">
        <div id="Product"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all questions must be in English. Please [edit] your question and translate it to English. Otherwise, it will get removed.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is an English language only site; you *may* have a better response over on [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: aqui habla ingles

Comment: Perguntas e respostas aqui devem ser escritas em inglês. Use http://pt.stackoverflow.com, por favor. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use http://pt.stackoverflow.com.)

Comment: OH... Sorry guys. I will edit my question.

Comment: @coreuter , ready. Tks.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, ready. tks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ready. Tks. Oh, nice your portuguese. haha tks .

Comment: @T.S. Tks thanks for the tip, sent well in spanish haha.

Comment: May I ask what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Off course. 
I am trying to display all the products in the array. I would like to take advantage of the structure and change only the id dynamically, so that the other products of the array are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want the loop that you commented out, and then to use `i` with `data.items[i]`, but you need to build up the HTML by adding to a string rather than replacing the string each time. See comments:

```
console.log(data.items);
var items = data.items; // *** Let's just call it `items`
var html = ""; // *** Start with a blank string
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {            
    // *** Use += to add to the `html` string
    // *** Note the ${items[i].id} and such
    html += `<div class="card" id="${items[i].id}">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="${items[i].image}" alt=" "/>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">${items[i].name}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">R$ ${items[i].price}</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">COMPRAR</a>
              </div>
          </div>`;
} // *** End of loop
jQuery('div#Product').html(html);
```

Live Example with the `getJSON` faked:

```js
// *** Fake items to show
var fakeItems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/375/0000FF/808080?text=Shirt+1",
        name: "Shirt 1",
        price: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/375/0000FF/808080?text=Shirt+2",
        name: "Shirt 2",
        price: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/375/0000FF/808080?text=Shirt+3",
        name: "Shirt 3",
        price: 30
    }
];
// *** Fake version of getJSON
function fakeGetJSON(url, callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 800, {items: fakeItems});
}
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {
      // *** The selector in this click handler is invalid, you can't start an ID
      // selector with an unescaped digit (#1)
      //j(document).on("click", "ul#menu li.nav-item#1", function() {
      j(document).on("click", "#shirts", function() {
        fakeGetJSON('/api/V1/categories/1', function(data) {
          console.log(data.items);
          var items = data.items; // *** Let's just call it `items`
          var html = ""; // *** Start with a blank string
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {   
              // *** Use += to add to the `html` string
              // *** Note the ${items[i].id} and such
              html += `<div class="card" id="${items[i].id}">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="${items[i].image}" alt=" "/>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${items[i].name}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">R$ ${items[i].price}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">COMPRAR</a>
            </div>
        </div>`;
          } // *** End of loop
          jQuery('div#Product').html(html);
        });
      });
}); // *** End the `ready` function call
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="shirts">Click me</div>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-7">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="ItemProd" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 mobile">
        <div id="Product"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- Don't just dump out `${items[i].name}` and such to HTML, if they have characters in them that mean something to HTML, it'll mess up your page. At a minimum, if outputting to the body of an element (not attributes!), you can just replace `&` with `&amp;` and then `<` with `&lt;`.
- Since you're using ES2015+ (I can tell from the template literals), you can:

  - Use `const` and `let` instead of `var`
  - Use `for-of` to loop through the array
  - Use destructuring in your `getJSON` callback's parameter list to just grab `items`: `getJSON("...", function({items}) {`

Comment: Amazing. That was it. I was on the right track, but I didn't do that dynamic part. About the products, how do I have them displayed horizontally?

Comment: @R.Park - Make your `.card` elements `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I tried the `display: inline-block` property, but it didn't work. = (

Comment: @R.Park - Since it's an entirely new issue, I suggest posting a new question about it, with enough HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem. Happy coding!

Comment: ok, Thank you very mutch.